# Anyway to require login in GAE through web.xml at a later stage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Platform: GAE + Java + GWT (plugin on Eclipse)

Requirement: Users must be able to use a shopping app to add contents to their cart but must be asked to login only during checkout.

Could the same module be accessed from two such urls:

- myapp.appspot.com/ (and myapp.appspot.com/myapp.html) requiring no login
- myapp.appspot.com/protected/checkout.html requiring login through web.xml

Is there some other way to achieve this through web.xml.

Don't want to check this at the server by redirecting to login page from Java code. **Can this be done purely through web.xml's security-constraints instead?**

Can't split into multiple modules because basic shopping (pre-checkout) should be possible both for logged in and unauthenticated users (from the same app+module).

New [Activities & Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) API seems to come close but didn't help with web.xml based restriction.

Comment: New to stackoverflow. Three weeks and no answer. Can I assume that this isn't possible through web.xml? Even a certainly '_not possible_' would be a very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a servlet filter mapped to the `/protected/*` URL pattern. This filter would check if the user is authenticated and redirect to the login page if not. You would have to do it manually, but it would be done at one unique place, without impacting the rest of the code.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html for more details about servlet filters.

The security-constraints, AFAIK, can't be used on GAE for authentication.

Comment: The question is about how to ensure this security works (beyond static pages) to the generated javascript? Can that go into /protected/ for the **same** module for a specific function (say checkout). How to show such a server split in web.xml before I could use the security-constraint?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're looking for. JEE web apps don't have a notion of a module. They have a notion of URL patterns. By mapping a filter to a URL pattern, all requests to any resource matching this pattern will go through the filter.

Comment: This '[Module](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_GWTModuleDefinition)' concept is specific to GWT. [More here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideModules). And hence the mention of the platform as the first line in the question though the tags cover the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  in the security constraint definition in web.xml to limit paricular paths

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

GAE talks about it in length:

https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication

Comment: Yes, I have used that with two modules or static pages etc. But how could I use that within the same module. Could say a specific function of a module point to `/protected/checkhout.html` while the rest to `/*`? As I mentioned in the question, I can't split the module and wish to do without java code purely through web.xml. Any solutions